# JOOQ kotlin gradle configuration doesent work

Tags: spring, kotlin, jooq

I am using spring boot with kotlin and gradle with groovy dsl. While configuring JOOQ, I stumble into a problem, where everytime I try to run codegen - I get this exception.

I get the same error again and again:

```
    23:31:53 WARNING org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 127; cvc-elt.1.a: Cannot find the declaration of element 'configuration'.

    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'java.lang.String org.jooq.meta.jaxb.Generator.getJava()'
    at org.jooq.codegen.GenerationTool.run0(GenerationTool.java:396)
    at org.jooq.codegen.GenerationTool.run(GenerationTool.java:246)
    at org.jooq.codegen.GenerationTool.generate(GenerationTool.java:241)
    at org.jooq.codegen.GenerationTool.main(GenerationTool.java:213)
```

This is my configuration in build.gradle:

```
jooq {
    edition = nu.studer.gradle.jooq.JooqEdition.OSS
    configurations {
        main {  // name of the jOOQ configuration
            generateSchemaSourceOnCompilation = false  // default (can be omitted)

            generationTool {
                logging = Logging.WARN
                jdbc {
                    driver = 'org.postgresql.Driver'
                    url = 'jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres'
                    user = 'postgres'
                    password = 'postgres'
                }
                generator {
                    name = 'org.jooq.codegen.KotlinGenerator'
                    database {
                        name = 'org.jooq.meta.postgres.PostgresDatabase'
                        inputSchema = 'public'
                        forcedTypes {
                            forcedType {
                                name = 'varchar'
                                includeExpression = '.*'
                                includeTypes = 'JSONB?'
                            }
                            forcedType {
                                name = 'varchar'
                                includeExpression = '.*'
                                includeTypes = 'INET'
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    generate {
                        deprecated = false
                        kotlinSetterJvmNameAnnotationsOnIsPrefix = true
                        pojosAsKotlinDataClasses = true
                        fluentSetters = true
                    }
                    target {
                        packageName = 'com.encryptora.vpn.infrastructure.database.jooq'
                        directory = 'generated-src/main/jooq'
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Also, can I somehow get the database properties from my application.yml rather than duplicating them here?

Comment: Does this example here help with your versioning problem? https://github.com/etiennestuder/gradle-jooq-plugin/tree/main/example/specify_jooq_config_xml_schema_version

Comment: @LukasEder unfortunately no. I tried pasting the buildscript {} section in the top of the gradle config, but the problem persists. Even changing the version to 3.16.1 does not help at all. As far as I can see, all my configuration is almost the same except database credentials part. I dont understand what is the problem in the first place tbh.

Comment: The problem is that you have a newer version of `jooq-codegen` and an older version of `jooq-meta`, but I don't know why that could happen. It wouldn't happen with the new official gradle plugin, where versions always match.

Comment: @LukasEder based on your point, I tried inspecting dependencies and actually found out that some jooq deps were swapped to 3.18.1 version for some reason. I tried to find the source of this but did not succed, in the end I explicitly put jooqGenerator jooq jooq-meta and jooq-codegen dependencies with 3.19.1 version and this solution worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The specific exception hints at `jooq-codegen` being of a newer version than `jooq-meta`. I.e. `jooq-codegen` expects there to be a method `org.jooq.meta.jaxb.Generator.getJava()`, which was added in jOOQ 3.19. Relevant changes were:

- [#15209](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/15209): Support ad-hoc compilation of programmatic GeneratorStrategy objects in the code generator
- [#15213](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/15213): Support ad-hoc compilation of programmatic Generator or Database objects in the code generator

But you probably have an older version of `jooq-meta` on your code generation classpath, which doesn't include this particular method (and many other methods) yet.

I don't know why this could happen with the third party gradle plugin that you're using, but the solution seems to be to explicitly specify all dependencies and their versions to be aligned.